# Puppeteer pdf always render html in 1024px width how to change that

Tags: c#, html, pdf, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I am using Puppeteer Sharp for HTML to pdf.
The issue is using media type print cause HTML to render at a width of 1024px, but I want to change that.

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MemoryStream> GeneratePuppeteerPDF(string html)
{
    var workStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions()
    {
        Headless = true,
        Timeout = 10000,
        ExecutablePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    }))
    {
        using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
        {
            await page.SetContentAsync(html);
            var pdfOptions = new PdfOptions()
            {
                DisplayHeaderFooter = false,
                Landscape = false,
                PrintBackground = true,
                Format = PaperFormat.A4,
                MarginOptions = new MarginOptions()
                {
                    Top = "1cm",
                    Bottom = "1cm",
                    Left = "1cm",
                    Right = "1cm"
                }
            };
            await page.EmulateMediaTypeAsync(MediaType.Print);
            var st = await page.PdfStreamAsync(pdfOptions);
            st.CopyTo(workStream);
        }
    }
    return workStream;
}
```

How can I control the render width of HTML without using **Media Type Screen**

Even using `Width` in `PdfOptions` won't work; please help. I didn't yet find any solution on stackOverflow or anyplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved. I am using Bootstrap 4, which had media print in the CSS.

```
@media print {
 @page {
   size: a3;
 }
 body {
   min-width: 992px !important;
 }
 .container {
   min-width: 992px !important;
 }
}
```

I overwrited the above by

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: auto;
  }

  body {
    min-width: 100% !important;
  }

  .container {
    min-width: 100% !important;
  }
 }
```

And now it's working if you set the div that holds the content to 600px, it will render in 600px width. You get what you see in the browser.